# How can I maintain the ability to type after using QLineEdit.selectAll?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want users of my app to be able to press the button, and then keep typing. With `QLineEdit.selectAll()`, I am able to select the text entered after `Run` is pressed, but typing won't do anything. See:

[image]

The text is selected due to `QLineEdit.selectAll()`, but typing won't do anything.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title = 'window title'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 75
        self.initUI()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.line = QLineEdit()
        label = QLabel('Enter a WORD:')

        run_button = QPushButton('Run')

        self.layout.addWidget(label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.layout.addWidget(run_button)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        run_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    def on_click(self):
        response = QLabel(self.line.text())

        self.layout.addWidget(response)
        self.line.selectAll()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectAll()` is tricky. It *looks* like the widget has the focus, but it doesn't. Use `setFocus()`. Order doesn't matter in this case

```
self.line.setFocus()
self.line.selectAll()
```

or

```
self.line.selectAll()
self.line.setFocus()
```

Further, in this UI, you can hook up the returnPressed signal of `self.line` to on_click so that when the user presses enter/return in self.line, the on_click method runs.

```
self.line.returnPressed.connect(self.on_click)
```

Putting it all together:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 75
        self.initUI()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.line = QLineEdit()
        label = QLabel('Enter a WORD:')

        run_button = QPushButton('Run')
        reset_button = QPushButton('Reset History')
        
        self.label = QLabel()               

        self.layout.addWidget(label)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.layout.addWidget(run_button)
        self.layout.addWidget(reset_button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)   

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        run_button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.line.returnPressed.connect(self.on_click)
        reset_button.clicked.connect(self.reset_click) 

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    def on_click(self):
        self.label.setText(self.label.text() + '\n' + self.line.text())  
        
        self.line.setFocus()
        self.line.selectAll()
        

    def reset_click(self):       
        self.label.setText('')   

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

By using this:

```
self.line.selectAll()
self.line.grabKeyboard()
```

It will select the text entered at every push of the button, and you will be able to continue typing without clicking in the textbox.